Yaml file not found when importing SpringBoot applications From Eclipse to IntelliJ
I want to try IntelliJ
My Eclipse IDE setup is configured using a workspace CoandaAirlines
On this workspace I have coanda-airlines that is a multi maven module project, 2 of those modules are spring boot applications: coandaairlines-config-provider and coandaairlines-backend.
coanda-airlines uses other 2 maven projects as dependency: davinci-framework and toolbox.
so basically my eclipse project explorer looks like that:

to replicate that on IntelliJ I have followed some tutorial.
I have created a folder called CoandaAirlinesWorkspace, and opened it as project, then I have imported the maven projects as modules, and now the project workspace looks like that:

Now I was trying to start a spring boot application, on Eclipse I have a launch configuration:

and is working as expected:

I have created a similar one on IntelliJ

but when I hit run button, is going in error, cause it not find the file for the spring.config.import
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec:3.3.0:exec (default-cli) @ coandaairlinesreservationsystem-config-provider ---
18:29:50.438 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter - 
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
Config data resource 'file [config/application-config-provider--local.yaml]' via location 'config/application-config-provider--local.yaml' does not exist
Action:
Check that the value 'config/application-config-provider--local.yaml' is correct, or prefix it with 'optional:'
[ERROR] Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:355)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:253)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:884)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:844)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:450)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:580)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)

I have tried by replacing:
--spring.config.import=config/application-config-provider--local.yaml

with
-Dspring.config.import=config/application-config-provider--local.yaml

It doesn't show "file does not exists", but the placeholders are not resolved:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.application.name' in value "${spring.application.name}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:180) ~[spring-core-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126) ~[spring-core-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:239) ~[spring-core-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210) ~[spring-core-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:200) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:921) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1374) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:784) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:767) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    ... 17 more


This question is not for this site. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

please post the actual stacktrace of the error - the screenshot provided barely shows anything

this is just a guess but I think the problem might be that u tried to import multiple projects under the same project. Therefore the run configuration is looking for the application-config-provider--local.yaml underl base directory, instead of the current projects directory. to test this, try using absolute path for the yaml file, and once confirmed just add the working directory to the run configuration (under Modify Options)

@JAsgarov working directory on the run configuration have solved the issue! Please provide as answer so I can accept it! Thanks a lot!

This is a somewhat common problem when using multi Projects in Intellij, which I am not sure why they can't fix:
When there are mutiple Projects, Intellij still treats the top folder as a baseDir, and all the run configurations look for relative paths starting from baseDir (and not how we, users, would expect, from project dir)
This can be fixed by:

going into the Run Configurations
Selecting Modify Options
Choosing Working Directory
Specifying the working directory you need (or you could also use intellij variable $MODULE_WORKING_DIR$)


thanks for suggesting $MODULE_WORKING_DIR$
